# Link between an equation and $SL_2$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $k$ a field.

It is assumed that it exists two matrixes $A,B \in SL_2(k)$ such as $AB = -BA$

Show that it exists $a,b,c \in k$ and $(a,b,c) \neq (0,0,0)$ such as $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = 0$

I have no idea how to begin. I tried to use the coefficients of $A$ but no success. if you have any suggest ...

Comment: What is the relation of $a,b,c$ to $A,B$?

Comment: @JohnB I think the statement is that the mere existence of matrices $A, B \in \mathrm{SL}_2(k)$ satisfying $AB = -BA$ implies that the quadratic form $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = 0$ has a solution in $k^\times$.

Comment: But if that's the case, then this fails in characteristic $2$, since e.g. we can take $k = \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, $A = B = I$, but $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = 0$ has no solutions with $a, b, c \neq 0$.

Comment: Sorry I have to correct the original post, it is $(a,b,c) \neq (0,0,0)$  sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hints.** Let $p(x)=x^2+1$. If $p(\lambda)=0$ for some $\lambda\in k$, we may simply pick $(a,b,c)=(\lambda,1,0)$.

If $p(x)=0$ has no root in $k$, we must have $\operatorname{char}(k)\ne2$. (Why?) Now, from $AB=-BA$, we obtain $A=-BAB^{-1}$. Therefore $\operatorname{tr}(A)=0$. Similarly, $\operatorname{tr}(B)=0$. The common characteristic polynomial of both $A$ and $B$ is therefore $p(x)=x^2+1$.

Since $p(x)=0$ has no root in $k$, $A$ is similar over $k$ to the companion matrix of $p$. So, we may assume that $A=\pmatrix{0&-1\\ 1&0}$. Using $\operatorname{tr}(B)=0$ and $AB=-BA$, can you tell what $B$ looks like? In turn, using $\det(B)=1$, can you obtain a relation between the elements of $B$?